# Zoom on specific MKMapView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, foursquare

My question is somehow related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916080/display-mkmapviewannotations-within-a-map-views-visible-rect). But with iOS7 I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it.

So basically I have a `MKMapView` working with a parallax effect, much like the Foursquare app.

[image]

So how can I zoom all the Annotations on the visible rect of the `MKMapView`?

Right now I have a working solution, that uses some values to offset the latitude of my annotations, but I find it very weird to do it.

---

**Detail:**

In order to give the map a parallax effect (when you are scrolling on the `UITableView`, the map is scrolling as well), you need to keep a part of the map bellow the table. In my case the `frame` of my `MKMapView` is `(0 -120; 320 390)` and the visible frame of it is  `(0 0, 320 150);`. So the goal here is to be able to show the annotations (zoom in) on that visible `frame`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, but I have not actually tried the code:

```
MKAnnotation* firstAnnotaiton = annotations[0];

CLLocationDegrees north = firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees south = firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees east = firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude;
CLLocationDegrees west = firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude;

for (int i = 1; i < annotations.count; i++)
{
    MKAnnotation* annotation = annotations[i];

    if (north < firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude)
        north = firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;
    if (south > firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude)
        south = firstAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;
    if (west < firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude)
        west = firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude;
    if (east > firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude)
        east = firstAnnotation.coordinate.longitude;
}

MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
    north,
    west
));
MKMapPoint lowerRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
    south,
    east
));

MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectMake(
    upperLeft.x,
    upperLeft.y,
    lowerRight.x - upperLeft.x,
    lowerRight.y - upperLeft.y
);

rect = [self.mapView mapRectThatFits:rect edgePadding:self.boundsInsets];

[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:rect animated:animated];
```

The key here is to have `self.boundsInsets` be a `UIEdgeInsets` specifying the difference between the views actual size and its visible bounds.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I've understood your question, but if not just explain in more detail and I can probably solve it for you.

Comment: I added more details @StefanFisk

Comment: cool, then this should work, just create an inset with 120px for top and bottom.

Comment: + any extra margin you might want (at least half the radius of whatever graphics you are using for the annotations)

Comment: In what place do I specify the `inset` and the zoom level?

Comment: `self.boundsInsets` is a property specifying the insets. the zoom is not settable directly, but is instead derived from the bounds of the annotations.

Comment: Ok let me put the question in another way: How do I specify the padding for the annotations? (extra padding will show map with less zoom)

Comment: you add it to boundsInsets, so if the radius of an annotation is 10px, then make the top/bottom insets 130px, and the left/right insets 10px.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45596/discussion-between-jacky-boy-and-stefan-fisk)